# Foreign key relation for Rest framework -- Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, foreign-keys

I am using Django and Restframework to create a API.

The data is I want the API output in such a way that "MasterResource" models is Parent, under that it filter the "Section" with matching "MasterResource" and then all the related "Items" matching with "Section".

My Models are currently look like this:

```
class MasterResource(models.Model):
    route_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    resourceId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class ResourceSection(models.Model):
    resourceId = models.ForeignKey(MasterResource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sectionId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)

class SectionItem(models.Model):
    sectionId = models.ForeignKey(ResourceSection, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    item_title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True)
    link = models.URLField()
```

And my views looks like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def create_resource(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        try:
            resourceId = request.POST.get("resourceId")
            route_name = request.POST.get("route_name")
            result = {}
            result['resourceDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',[MasterResource.objects.get(resourceId=resourceId)]))
            result['sectionDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',ResourceSection.objects.filter(resourceId__resourceId = resourceId)))
            result['itemDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',SectionItem.objects.filter(sectionId__sectionId=sectionId)))
            return JsonResponse(result, safe=False)
        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(e)
```

I have achieved to receive data of "MasterResource" and its related "Sections", but the related "Items" arenot giving output

Current output

```
{
    "resourceDetails": [
        {
            "model": "userdata.masterresource",
            "pk": "1234",
            "fields": {
                "route_name": "Testing test"
            }
        }
    ],
    "sectionDetails": [
        {
            "model": "userdata.resourcesection",
            "pk": "112233",
            "fields": {
                "resourceId": 1234,
                "resource_name": "Test section"
            }
        },
        {
            "model": "userdata.resourcesection",
            "pk": "223344",
            "fields": {
                "resourceId": 1234,
                "resource_name": "Test section2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "itemDetails": []
}
```

Required output something like this:

```
{
    "resourceDetails": [
        {
            "model": "userdata.masterresource",
            "pk": "1234",
            "fields": {
                "route_name": "Testing test"
            }
        }
    ],
    "sectionDetails": [
        {
            "model": "userdata.resourcesection",
            "pk": "112233",
            "fields": {
                "resourceId": 1234,
                "resource_name": "Test section"
            }
        },
        {
            "model": "userdata.resourcesection",
            "pk": "223344",
            "fields": {
                "resourceId": 1234,
                "resource_name": "Test section2"
            }
        }
    ],
    "itemDetails": [
    {
      "model" : "userdata.sectionitem",
      "pk": "1",
      "fields" : {
        "sectionId" : 112233
        "item_title" : "test"
        "image" : "some_image"
        "link" : "www.google.com"
      }
    }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for the above problem.

Since we need a output of all the items of a section then we need to provide a key or id for which we need the items for.

That means instead of only `resourceId = request.POST.get("resourceId")`, there has to be another POST data to mention which Item data is required, which is `sectionId = request.POST.get("sectionId")` just below the resourceId.

And hence the serialize data it will become `result['itemDetails'] = json.loads(serializers.serialize('json',SectionItem.objects.filter(sectionId__sectionId=sectionId)))`